# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass within simple form with two partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two partials that route to the same controller and same model. In both of these partials I am submitting a new form, which I am intending on using the `create` method in my controller. My first partial is simply called `_form.html.haml` and it works quite well.  However my second partial I have called `_case_study_form.html.haml`. My second partial is where I am having some problems. The issue that I am getting is `undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass`. I believe that I am getting this issue because my second partial has a different name, I don't understand why I am getting this error as I feel like I have routed the model in the correctly.

My model is named `form_submission.rb`

My first partial, `_form.html.haml` I have my first line set up as

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission do |f|
```

My second partial, `_case_study_form.html.haml` I am having troubles with my first line and have it set up as

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission, url: case_study_path do |f|
```

My controller is

```
class FormSubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  invisible_captcha only: [:create, :case_study], on_spam: :handle_spam

  def new
    @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new
  end

  def create
    @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def case_study
  end

  private

    def handle_spam
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def form_submission_params
      params.require(:form_submission).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :email, :phone, :recognition, :inquiry, :form_submission)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@form_submission` object initialised inside the method `case_study` as well. The `url` you mention in the form represents the form submit action controller method. I.e., once you submit the form, it will go to that url.

```
def case_study
  @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new
end
```